# Android app adding toolbar causes exception

Tags: android-studio, android-layout, kotlin

I thought I should add a toolbar as I'll need a *settings* button.

So I added this to my `main_activity.xml`

```
    <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
        android:id="@+id/toolbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:title="PSA MFD"
        app:subtitle="Multi functional display for Citroen and Peugeot"
        app:logo="@android:drawable/ic_menu_call"
        app:navigationIcon="@drawable/ic_fan"
 />
```

But now my app won't run because:

```
    java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.rwb.psamfd/com.rwb.psamfd.MainActivity}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #10: Binary XML file line #10: Error inflating class android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2646)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2707)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap12(ActivityThread.java)
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1460)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6077)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:866)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:756)
     Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #10: Binary XML file line #10: Error inflating class android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
     Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #10: Error inflating class android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
     Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar" on path: DexPathList[[zip file "/data/app/com.rwb.psamfd-2/base.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app/com.rwb.psamfd-2/lib/x86, /system/lib, /vendor/lib]]
        at dalvik.system.BaseDexClassLoader.findClass(BaseDexClassLoader.java:56)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:380)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:312)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:609)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:787)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:727)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:858)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflateChildren(LayoutInflater.java:821)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:518)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:426)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:377)
        at androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatDelegateImpl.setContentView(AppCompatDelegateImpl.java:555)
        at androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity.setContentView(AppCompatActivity.java:161)
        at com.rwb.psamfd.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.kt:31)
        at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6662)
        at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1118)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2599)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2707)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap12(ActivityThread.java)
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1460)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6077)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:866)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:756)
```

What do I ned to do? I have absolutely no idea. (I'm new to Android development -- and it's very difficult compared to C#).

Comment: BTW `android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar` switch to androidx: https://developer.android.com/jetpack/androidx/migrate

Comment: What?
I can't find anything in there about toolbars.
Where am I supposed to be looking?
Why would I need to _migrate_ anything if it's a new project?
What is `androidx` anyway? And how can I tell if I'm doing it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Method 1:

Add the following to your dependencies in build.gradle file:

```
dependencies {
  ...
  **implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.0.0'**
}
```

And change your toolbar as:

```
<androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar
  ....
  Your contents
  ....>
<androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar/>
```

Method 2:

You can migrate to androidx directly.

Hope you will find the solution.

Comment: Ah, so I was using the wrong `Toolbar` tag. Thank you, that works now.